# Intento pasar un checkbox a string

Tags: php, html

el problema aqui es que , no tengo manera de hacerlo porque en el formulario le puse un sumador , y usa el valué para poder agarrar los números como podría pasar el checkbox al correo?

PRIMER FORMULARIO

```
 <!-- ESTE ES EL PRIMER FORMULARIO QUE ENVIA LA INFORMACION -->
    <div class="t945">
    <div class="adaptable">
    <div class="Form-Corp">
       <form  action="correo.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off" class="Form-Caja">
          <div class="Form-Principal">
           <h1 class="Form-Title">Arma Tu Pizza</h1>
           </div>
           <input type="text" id="input-totalmente-falso" style="display: none">
           <label for="Nombre" class="Form-Label"></label>
           <input type="text" autofocus autocomplete="off" id="Nombre" class="Input-Form" name="Name" placeholder="Nombre" required>
           <label for="Correo" class="Form-Label"></label>
           <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="Correo" class="Input-Form" name="Correo" placeholder="Correo" required>
           <label for="Direccion" class="Form-Label"></label>
           <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="Direccion" class="Input-Form" name="Direccion" placeholder="Direccion" required>
           <label for="Elige tu Sabor" class="Form-Label"></label>
           <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="Paladar" class="Input-Elige" name="Sabor" placeholder="INGREDIENTES" required>
           <!---------------------------------->
           <!---------------------------------->
           <input type="radio" class="button1" name="Pago" value="EFECTIVO" checked><p class="PA-1">Efectivo</p><br>
           <input type="radio" class="button2" name="Pago" value="PUNTO DE VENTA" checked><p class="PA-2">Punto De Venta</p><br>
           <a href="javascript:PRICE()"><input type="button" id="Consultar" class="Input-Price" value="Mostrar Ingredientes"></a>
           <div class="tot">
              <label class="DIV" for="txtValor"></label>
              <input  type="text" name="tot" readonly id="txtValor" value="0" />
          </div>
           <input  id="SEND" type="image"  img src="send.png" height="50px" width="50px" class="Boton-Submit" name="Submit" value="enviar">
           <p class="Form-Label1">PEDIDOS</p>
       </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

(SEGUNDO FORMULARIO)
Este formulario donde se selecciona los iconos para sumar o enviar lo que seleccionaron al correo

```
<div class="adapF">
  <div class="wrapper" id="OPEN">
  <div class="sub_wrapper">
    <div class="hobby">
     <form action="correo.php" method="post">
      <label class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" name="modulo[]"  title="JAMON" class="input" id="chk_1"  value="1.00" onclick="actualizarValor(this.checked, this.value);">
        <span class="d_checkbox"></span>
        <img  class="fas" src="jamon.png" title="" width="55px" height="55px">
      </label>
      </form>
      </div>


    <div class="hobby">
      <form action="correo.php" method="post">
      <label class="container">
      <input type="checkbox" name="modulo[]" title="PEPERONI" class="input" id="chk_1" value="1.00" onclick="actualizarValor(this.checked, this.value);">
      <span class="d_checkbox"></span>
       <img  class="fas" src="pepperoni.png" width="55px" height="55px">
    </label>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Aqui anexe el contenido del Correo php
correo.php

```
<?php
 $Destino  = "alguien@gmail.com";
 $Nombre   =  $_POST["Name"];
 $Correo   =  $_POST["Correo"];
 $Delivery =  $_POST["Direccion"];
 $Mensaje  =  $_POST["Sabor"];
 $Metodo   =  $_POST["Pago"];
 $Total    =  $_POST["tot"];
 $Contenido= "Name: ". $Nombre . "\nCorreo: " . $Correo  . "\nDireccion: " . $Delivery . "\n\n" . "\nSabor: " .$Mensaje . "\nPago: ". $Metodo .  "\nTotal Que Pagara: " .  $Total;
 mail($Destino,"contacto", $Contenido);
 header("Location:gracias.html");
```

a ver si me puedo explicar un poco mejor lo que puse en el **primer formulario** solo fue para que escriban información como nombre y correo ,ahora mediante una ventana emergente puse el **segundo formulario** que tienen para seleccionar y que al seleccionar ellas suman un valor (entonces lo que quiero hacer en ese segundo formulario es sumar y enviar lo que seleccionaron de los check)

Comment: No es muy clara tu pregunta. Se supone que al enviar el formulario vas a tener en `$_POST` los datos del formulario que fueron enviados. En `$_POST["modulo[]"]` tendrás los datos del checkbox en caso de que éste haya sido seleccionado. Yo me refiero al archivo `correo.php`, que el archivo hacia el cual van a ser enviados los datos del formulario.

Comment: si exacto en la variable  name modulo[] va almacenada el nombre del item que selecionar, pero cuando llega al correo , llega vacio . en donde dice valué se supone que debería poner el nombre del ítem para que llegue al correo con el nombre.Pero no lo puedo hacer porque tengo otro script que agarra el valor de valué. y lo suma  a medida que seleccionan ítem      @A.Cedano

Comment: Si ver la forma en que recibes y manipulas los datos en `correo.php` es difícil ayudarte. Por favor pulsa en [edit] y agrega el contenido de ese archivo.

Comment: en ese contenido de php , tiene anexado un form que esta en los div del html ahora lo que yo digo tambien es para que otro formulario que tengo en el mismo html envié los checkbox ..

Comment: No hay ningún `$_POST["modulo[]"]` ahí. Tomando en cuenta además que en esa clava lo que habrá es un array y que debes sacar los valores como `implode` o de otro modo y agregarlo al cuerpo del email.

Comment: yo los modulo[] los quite porque veía que no estaban funcionado por eso es que en el contenido correo.php no contienen eso

Comment: Intenta por ejemplo algo así: `$modulo=implode(", ",$_POST["modulo[]"]);` y agregas eso al contenido con: `$Contenido= "Name: ". $Nombre . "\nCorreo: " . $Correo  . "\nDireccion: " . $Delivery . "\n\n" . "\nSabor: " .$Mensaje . "\nPago: ". $Metodo .  "\nTotal Que Pagara: " .  $Total. "\nMódulo: ". $modulo;`

Comment: Quizá cometiste un error ¿? Muestra cómo tienes `$Contenido` creado ahora.

Comment: el php envio la informacion al correo , pero lo envió.  **modulo:** ... ya me había percatado del error parte era un punto y coma , ahora el modulo. se envía pero vacio

Comment: OK, prueba a ponerlo así: `$modulo=implode(", ",$_POST["modulo"]);`, me parece que en el POST no hay que usar ya `[]` Asegúrate de que el checkbox está chequeado al enviar el form, si no `modulo` se enviaría vacío.

Comment: Tambien me los envia vacio, creo que la solucion sera separar los checkbox  un checkbox diferente para sumar y otro para enviar los ítem seleccionado porque veo que todo junto no me funciona. GRACIAS por tomarte tu tiempo y ayudarme en mi problema te lo agradezco aunque no haya dado como quería jeje , muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Debería funcionar así, a no ser que aquí `onclick="actualizarValor(this.checked, this.value);` hagas algo raro que modifique el estado del checkbox o el value del mismo. Sería interesante ver lo que arroja un `var_dump(_$POST);` en `correo.php` para ver lo que está llegando desde el formulario. Otra cosa que veo es que tienes dos `form`, entonces ten en cuenta que no se envían los dos juntos, sino uno, al que le des a su botón enviar. Aunque  tampoco veo los botones enviar de ninguno de los formularios ¿?

Comment: **onclick="actualizarValor(this.checked, this.value);** eso  es una parte del script para hacer que sume los ítem que van seleccionando voy a tratar de escribir el código del html completo para que se pueda entender mejor